# how can i close view after completion of playing sound

Tags: iphone

hi i am new to iphone. what i did is displaying a grid of images and by selecting the image from the grid selected image will be displayed on imageview along with sound i am using the fallowing code to play audio

```
NSString *newAudioFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@”MusicFile”  ofType:@”mp3″];
AVAudioPlayer *audioPlayer =  [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:newAudioFile] error:NULL];

[audioPlayer play];
```

Now what i need is how can i get to view after completion of playing sound file
post some code. thank u.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `– audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying:successfully:` method of you AVAudioPlayer *delegate* (probably your UIViewController) and inside of it you can dismiss the view releasing it and doing `[myView removeFromSuperview]`

Have a look [at this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1111691/do-an-action-when-a-sound-has-finished-playing-in-avaudioplayer)

Comment: i cant able to go in that function. pls post any link regarding this topic

Comment: what do you mean by 'go in that function'?